# Arrange two full sized divs below each other

Tags: html, css

I have two divs like following:

```
<div class="div-one">
 <p>Div 1</p>
</div>
<div class="div-two">
 <p>Div 2</p>
</div>
```

And in my css:

```
.div-one{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.div-two{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

I want to arrange these two divs bellow each other and each one of them occupies full screen (imagine a landing page). At a time only one div is visible on the screen and then user can scroll to see the other.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On way you can do this is with viewport relative units:

```
.div-one {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.div-two {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

`1vh` is equal to 1% of the viewport height. `1vw` is equal to 1% of the viewport width. (also `vmin` is the lesser of the two `vmax` for the greater.) These are supported in most but not all modern browsers. So you might want to provide a reasonable fallback value:

```
.div-one {
  min-height: 500px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.div-two {
  min-height: 500px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

You don’t need the widths, as block-level elements are already width auto (which will basically be 100%), and you probably don’t want to use positioning if they are to flow normally in the page, one after the other.

Comment: And what if both of them have a body tag outside which is set to 100%? will that affect the result of your answer?

Comment: Nice btw `.div-one` is listed twice

Comment: @Nitish Not OP, but I can answer this.  `vw` is relative to the viewport ("the part of the browser that is taken up by visible website content" [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Viewport)).  It is not affected by the `body` or `html` tag dimensions.  It's just the visible area when viewing through a browser.  It is affected by resizing the window or rotating the mobile device.  Also, support is really high now for modern browsers, especially if you opt to not use `vmin`/`vmax`: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: Thanks for this explanation!